# img onClick"" doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, display

HTML

```
<img src="http://i.pr3cast.pw/02.09.10z.png" onClick="disappear()">
```

JS

```
function disappear() {
document.getElementsByTagName("img").style.display = "none"; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1y42d7zm/

Nothing happens to the image when I click :(

Console says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

Thanks

Comment: The `.getElementsByTagName()` function returns a **list** of elements, even when there's only one matching element on the page.

Comment: o.o what should I use then?

Comment: You can use that, but you have to then extract the actual target image from the list. Exactly how you do that depends on the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function(){
  window.disappear = function() {
     console.log("dissapear");
     document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style = "display: none;"; 
  };
 }());
```

You almost had it. As others have mentioned, document.getElementsByTagName returns an array; you have to specify the element you want `[0]`.

I changed your disappear function to be tied to the window as I wasn't able to access it via my CodePen. The closure `(function(){}())` makes it so that the code will run when the dom is ready.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Treeless/pen/oBQyyG)

Comment: No, your code won't work either, for exactly the same reason that the OP code won't.

Comment: Please don't leave out semicolons.

Comment: And don't use CodePen when you can do just as well with a Stack Snippet.

Comment: You should explain what you changed and why, not just post code that challenges the reader to understand why.

Comment: @Barmar Stack Snippet? :S  Where do I use that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].style = "display: none;"; ` This is what I needed, so I'll mark this as the right answer. Still, what does "[0]" do? Thanks

Comment: @blex I just checked several of my answers that have stack snippets, they work just fine.

Comment: @blex Such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148920/array-of-array-to-object-javascript/42149025#42149025

Comment: @Barmar Made the changes. I guess for next time I'll make sure to use a stack snippet, thanks for mentioning it :)

Comment: @Barmar Ok, then the bug might be local to my area/country: http://imgur.com/a/JoGdO

Comment: @PrecastDragon The [0] grabs the first element from the array that is returned by: `document.getElementsByTagName("img")`. :)

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<img id="to-disappear" src="http://i.pr3cast.pw/02.09.10z.png"         onClick="disappear()">
```

JS:

```
function disappear() {
    document.getElementById("to-disappear").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: it has to use an ID? I was trying to avoid that, I don't want to have to tag every single img element if I want to animate all of them, I'm pretty sure there must be a different way, right?

Comment: @PrecastDragon The different way is in the other answer.

Comment: You have to do the iteration over the set of matched elements yourself.