# Array of an array to object list (without extra array) in output

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Using [Array of array to object - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148920/array-of-array-to-object-javascript) and    [Convert an array to an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807804/convert-an-array-to-an-array-of-objects) as a guide I tried to write a function that results in 
taking this array of array list:

```
var list = [['name', 'Sparky'], ['breed', 'lab'], ['age', 4]];
```

and converting it into this:

```
{
  name : 'Sparky'
  breed : 'lab',
  age : 4
}
```

However, when I run the code below:

```js
var list = [
  ['name', 'Sparky'],
  ['breed', 'lab'],
  ['age', 4]
];

function toObjects(data) {
  var keys = data.shift(),
    i = 0,
    k = 0,
    obj = null,
    output = [];

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    obj = {};

    for (k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
      obj[keys[k]] = data[i][k];
    }

    output.push(obj);
  }

  return output;
}
var data = [
  ['name', 'Sparky'],
  ['breed', 'lab'],
  ['age', 4]
];

console.log(toObjects(data))
```

I get this:

```
console.log(toObjects(data)); //=> 

[ { name: 'breed', Sparky: 'lab' },{ name: 'age', Sparky: 4 } ]
```

but I need the output to not have an extra array [ ] and to also be listed single file like this:

```
       {
          name : 'Sparky'
          breed : 'lab',
          age : 4
        }
```

Any advice? Please and thank you!

Comment: Then define `output` as  `{}` and instead of `obj[..][..]` do `output[..][..]`

Comment: Can't you do `list.reduce((accu, curVal) => { accu[curVal[0]] = curVal[1]; return accu; }, {})`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to perform your transformation as well as argument [destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Take a look, the code is pretty simple :)

```js
let list = [
  ['name', 'Sparky'],
  ['breed', 'lab'],
  ['age', 4]
];

function toObjects(data) {
  // reduce iterates through every element in the `data` array
  // and accumulates it into the object

  let initialValue = {};
  return data.reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
    obj[key] = value;
    return obj;
  }, initialValue); // this could be in-lined with `{}`
}

var data = [
  ['name', 'Sparky'],
  ['breed', 'lab'],
  ['age', 4]
];

console.log(toObjects(list))
```

Comment: @Rajesh I just wanted to name it something to show what's going on. I'll rename it again

Comment: Thanks @Rico, this is what I  was looking for!!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use map function to achieve this

```js
var list = [['name', 'Sparky'], ['breed', 'lab'], ['age', 4]];
var newObj = new Object();
list.forEach(function (arr) {
   newObj[arr[0]] = arr[1];
});

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: I don't think OP is looking for alternatives. Object of this question is to get output as object and not array.

Comment: Downvote because you are using `Array.map` without returning anything and assigning. This is just wasting `Array.map`. If you just want to process array, use `Array.forEach`

Comment: `newObj[arr[0]] = arr[1];` is used within `map`.

Comment: `Array.map` is used to map values based on current values. You are not returning anything inside `.map`  so it will return `undefined`. You are not saving output anywhere as well. This is classic case for `.forEach`. A user with your rep should know this